# Problem importing Android project archives into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, archive

My apologies if this is a stupid newbie question...

I'm using Eclipse (Helios release) and have the Android SDK all configured as per the developer.android.com recommendations. I can create and run new projects without any problem but I can't import archived project code samples (found on the web etc.) using Import > Existing Projects Into Workspace.

Importing a zip creates a project but it doesn't create it as an Android project and the console displays the error: "Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one."

I've tried going into the project Properties but as soon as I click on 'Android' in the properties tree a pop-up appears saying "Could Not Accept Changes: The currently displayed page contains invalid values"

See: http://screencast.com/t/ZmY3ZWQ4

But if I do this on one of my own projects I have no such error, and I'm able to change things such as the Android Platform/API level. I'm also able to archive my own projects (using export) and import them again without any problems... nut not other people's archives! Am I being really stupid?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem -- for example, I can't import the projects from http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/ -- I get the same set of errors.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

All the baseline default.properties needs is a line like:

`target=android-8`

You can most likely copy another projects' default.properties into this project. A (not-so-)quick restart of Eclipse, a rebuilding of the workspace, and you're off to the races.

It's really lame that this is needed -- it should happen as part of the import process, I would think.

Comment: If I could upvote more than once, I'd do it. Was having the same problem, and this fixed it for me perfectly. The key part was copying a default.properties file into the project.

Comment: I think this happens due to different version of ADT.

Comment: default.properties has been [renamed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319703/project-properties-in-android-project) to project.properties.

Answer (score 7):

just change your

```
project.properties file to default.properties
```

and restart your eclipse

it's done..

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project in navigator window, go to android tools and click on fix project properties. It might work, as it did for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this section, it works for me:
[Project has no default.properties file!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426011/project-has-no-default-properties-file/4791378#4791378)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the library of your  project, do that :
- right click on the project name
- Build Path
- Configure build path
- click Android on the left, and select the library you need.

Comment: That's what I would have assumed, but as you'll see from my question (and screencast) as soon as I click on 'Android' on the left, I get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
What you are trying is little difficult.Just unzip the files ,copy res and src folders
to ur existing project.The problem is the files starting with "." which have settings for their android and eclipse.
So you need to modify all that,so simply create new project or to ur existing one copy res, src and AndroidManifest.xml file.
It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

In the project right click  `Android Tools` -> `Fix Project Properties`