# Project has no default.properties file!

Tags: android

I downloaded a sample project from a website. when i import this project to eclipse work space. Im getting this error

**Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.**

How i can get rid of this problem. Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Are we allowed to see the project you downloaded? Supply a link and we'll try to help you.

Comment: this is the link where i downloaded
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use create new project from existing sources option in Eclipse with the location pointing to downloaded project directory.

Comment: I agree, import never seems to work with android projects.

Answer (score 5):

Also see [project.properties in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319703/project-properties-in-android-project). In ADT 14, default.properties was renamed to project.properties.

Quote from the changelog:

> default.properties which is the main project’s properties file
>   containing information such as the build platform target and the
>   library dependencies has been renamed project.properties.

See build [changes in revision 14](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14), at the bottom under "Project Setup"

Answer (score 4):

Solution found on a [blog](http://www.stevenmarkford.com/android-eclipse-error-project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one/):

1. Delete Eclipse specific files and folders (eg. “.settings”, “.project” “.metadata” etc.) from your Android project folder.
2. Open up Eclipse and ensure your Android project is removed from the Project Explorer.
3. From the Eclipse Project Explorer create a new Android project from your existing Android files.

Answer (score 1):

Simply rename your project.properties file to default.properties ... You got it done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update ADT and the Android SDK.