# Building project in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've looked for an answer, no luck. Looked a lot. 
I've downloaded an android example project from a friend, it's all in the correct layout, and the source files are there. Only I wish to open the whole project in eclipse, so that I can run it using the emulator I have installed. However, I cannot seem to be able to do this. I have all versions of android installed, and I have been advised that the files/project are for 2.3 so should be good. Have tried:

File --> New Android Project --> Using the existing file and build path
It suggested to do file --> Import instead, so went there and imported an android project from existing workspace.

It gave this error: 
"Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one".

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/3857576/776084 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3426011/776084

Comment: you can create this file and input 'target=10'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New version of ADT plugin uses project.properties while older version use default.properties.

Please upgrade ADT plugin. It will work

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to open one of my projects on a different computer, you need to update the ADT. In Eclipse go to Help > Install New Software. Type in https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and install the latest versions of everything. Also make sure everything to do with the SDK is up to date!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project from existing source.