# Unable to change Project Target from Properties

Tags: android

Error occurred(An error occurred. see error log for more details. Widget is disposed) while changing the project target from project properties. And even project target some times cannot be seemed in the table.
     Can any one help with an ideas...
Thanks

Comment: `An error occurred. see error log for more details. Widget is disposed` Can you post the error log that SDK suggest us to see?

Answer (score 0):

if any other projet have default.properties file then copy that file at same place in your project and refresh the project in eclipse and now try to change .............

or

[Project has no default.properties file!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426011/project-has-no-default-properties-file)

Comment: Can you please let me know is there any difference between "Changing target from Project Tab(above)->Properties  & Right clicking in project source-->Properties-->Android")

Comment: we just have different ways to open this place but finally this is the place from where you change the target...