# project.properties in android project

Tags: java, android

I just cloned this from [github](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) and when I tried to import it to eclipse as an android project, it doesn't have a default.properties. Why is this and how do I handle this?

Answer (score 18):

*project.properties* is the same thing as *default.properties*, it just got renamed with ADT 14.
And *project.properties* is in the github repo you linked, therefore it should work out of the box if you have the most recent version of the tools. Otherwise update them.

Quote from the changelog:

> default.properties which is the main project’s properties file
>   containing information such as the build platform target and the
>   library dependencies has been renamed project.properties.

*See [build changes in revision 14](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14), at the bottom under "Project Setup"*