# What is the diff. between default.properties and project.properties?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wanted to inquire what the difference was between the default.properties and project.properties files in an Android project. Tried googling it but no proper answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`default.properties which is the main project’s properties file containing information such as the build platform target and the library dependencies has been renamed project.properties.`
For more see a link:[project.properties in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319703/project-properties-in-android-project)