# Is default.properties and project.properties the same in Android?

Tags: android

I just want to know whether the `default.properties` and `project.properties` is the same in an Android project. If no, then where can I find the default.properties file in my Android project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the diff. between default.properties and project.properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515586/what-is-the-diff-between-default-properties-and-project-properties)

Comment: explanation between these two  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one

Comment: and that too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319703/project-properties-in-android-project