# Can't import projects into Eclipse workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, import

So, I have been using eclipse in Windows for years. I have a few android projects that I have been working on lately. But I'm getting stuck on something so weird.

The problem is I'm using eclipse on both windows and Linux now. (Yeah i feel linux is better and much faster). I want to get all my projects that I was using on Windows into Linux Eclipse workspace (Yes I created another workspace because I didnt know if I could work on same workspace in both versions viz linux and windows eclipse). Now, the weird part is **I CANNOT IMPORT THOSE PROJECTS INTO MY OTHER WORKSPACE!** This is driving me crazy.

I go to my Linux Eclipse workspace -> Import -> Add existing android proj -> browse -> Root dir of my android project -> (Ecipse does show the projects on the frame below -> I click finish -> **NOTHING**. I just sit there, waiting, and nothing happens. I have searched around here in stackoverflow, but none of the problems resembles this.

Yes I have access to the workspace folder, yes I can create folders, etc etc.

Please can someone tell me how I can import projects that are being detected but NOT imported?

thanks.

Comment: Oh and by the way, I'm using Eclipse Juno on both windows and linux, if it helps answer the question!

Comment: change your workspace to project location, create new project and use existing files  might work

Comment: I cant see that option "Use existing files" when I make a new android project...

Comment: I am having the same problem.  all the files seem legit, and the answer doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem importing Android project archives into Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311474/problem-importing-android-project-archives-into-eclipse)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by importing the project in the following manner:

`File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace`

Click `Next`, then `Browse...`

Select your project root directory, and check the box for `Copy projects into workspace`. Click `Finish`.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This solution seems to result in the exact same scenario as the OP's. I'm not sure what it offers as a fix.

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same problem for long, today only I found out the solution!

It's all lies in .project and .classpath files inside project's root directory. While trying to import any project into workspace, if your project does not gets listed, that means .project and/or .classpath files are either missing or corrupt. Usually these files are hidden, so you never know what is the issue.

For Ubuntu, follow steps below:

**step 1.** go to any project root directory in your workspace and press Ctrl+H to see hidden files.

**step 2.** copy .project and .classpath files from there and paste to the other project directory that you wanted to import.

**step 3.** Open the .project file and update name tag to project name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
 <name>Name of the project</name>
 <comment></comment>
 ....
```

**step 4.** close the folder and import the project, it will be definitely listed in the import wizard now!!

Comment: Thank you very much worked like a charm, silly Eclipse causing such problems.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same problem.

you need to **update ADT** (Eclipse Plugin) to work with new Android SDK.

click **Help > Check for Updates**

after ADT updated, you can import your project from **File > Import**

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check to see if the **AndroidManifest.xml** file is present in either the folder or a sub folder. You must have that file in order to import.

This is the issue I had. Luckily I have the unlimited history feature in DropBox so I was able to use that to get the last existing version of the file. Once I added it, importing worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the project already exists in the workspace.  The solution is to either change your workspace location or just rename the project you're importing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, here what i have done.
- In Eclipse, Go to windows -> Preferences
- choose Android, set your Android SDK Location
  make sure you have at least one of the Android platform in the table.
- Apply and Ok.

done, I try import, and it's fine.
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

After importing the file, you can deselect the in library from properties section. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if all the sulotions above didnt help you, open a new project with the same name as the imported project,after you do that, go to the Original project,open it and selcet all files with **ctrl+A**,and than copy paste it inside the new project,then click **yes to all**  inside the alaert and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

If none of the above answers help, check the permissions of the folder which contains the projects. In Ubuntu from command line try this:

```
sudo chmod 777 Folder_Containing_Projects -R
```

The above command will give permissions recursively.